# How to add rows to a datagrid / datatable in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatable

What I want to do is to hide and show columns in runtime with a Datagrid.

I'm using MVVM, and I have a DataGrid with the ItemsSource like this:

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding ComponentsPropertiesGrid}" 
 views:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding dataGridColumn}"
```

where DataGridColumnsBehavior is the following class.

```
public class DataGridColumnsBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableColumns",
                                            typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>),
                                            typeof(DataGridColumnsBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableColumnsPropertyChanged));
    private static void BindableColumnsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid = source as DataGrid;
        ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> columns = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>;
        dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
        if (columns == null) { return; }

        foreach (DataGridColumn column in columns)
        {
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        columns.CollectionChanged += (sender, e2) =>
        {
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs ne = e2 as NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs;
            if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
                if (ne.NewItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                    {
                        dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                if (ne.NewItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.NewItems)
                    {
                        dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Move(ne.OldStartingIndex, ne.NewStartingIndex);
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                if (ne.OldItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridColumn column in ne.OldItems)
                    {
                        dataGrid.Columns.Remove(column);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (ne.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                dataGrid.Columns[ne.NewStartingIndex] = ne.NewItems[0] as DataGridColumn;
            }
        };
    }
    public static void SetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element, ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> value)
    {
        element.SetValue(BindableColumnsProperty, value);
    }
    public static ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> GetBindableColumns(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)element.GetValue(BindableColumnsProperty);
    }
}
```

At this point, I can add and remove columns propertly in Runtime just adding/removing them to the dataGridColumn Collection only when my datatable does not have columns. And if I don't have columns in my datatable, how do I add rows??

```
 DataRow newRow = ComponentsPropertiesGrid.NewRow();

 newRow[componentName] = "Test";
```

When I try that, It throws an exception, because componentName is not a valid column in the dataTable.

If there is another way to do it we can try it.

Comment: Have you tried setting AutoGenerateColums to false on your grid?

Comment: I just tried it, and it works without exceptions, but the DataGrid doesn't show any values inside cells, despite I am doing
`DataRow newRow = ComponentsPropertiesGrid.NewRow();    newRow[componentName] = "Test";`